# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 when using lda package in python

Tags: python, lda

I tried using the lda 1.0.2 package in python 3. Attaching my code snippet.
Trials:
 I am not creating a separate dictionary, so not sure why I am hitting this error. (most of the links suggested a broken dictionary).
 I tried to create a ndarray instead of a matrix. But that gives "Need more than 0 values to unpack" error.

```
dataset = load_files(path, encoding = 'utf-8' )
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_features=10000,
                             stop_words='english')
data_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset.data)
#data_array = numpy.asarray(data_vector) 
import lda
model = lda.LDA(n_topics= 5)
data_lda = model.fit(data_vector);
```

The code fails at model.fit(...)

I am new to python. It would be very helpful if someone could explain the logic too. Thanks.

EDIT:Attaching the complete trace.
    `IndexError : Traceback (most recent call last)`
    `import lda
    4 model = lda.LDA(n_topics= 1)
    ----> 5 data_lda = model.fit(data_vector);`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda/lda.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
118        Returns the instance itself.
119         """
--> 120         self._fit(X)
121         return self
122 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda/lda.pyc in _fit(self, X)
212  random_state = lda.utils.check_random_state(self.random_state)
213         rands = self._rands.copy()
--> 214         self._initialize(X)
215         for it in range(self.n_iter):
216  # FIXME: using numpy.roll with a random shift might be faster

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda/lda.pyc in _initialize(self, X)
255         np.testing.assert_equal(N, len(WS))
256         for i in range(N):
--> 257             w, d = WS[i], DS[i]
258             z_new = i % n_topics
259             ZS[i] = z_new

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'
```

Comment: Check the size of `dataset.data` and `data_vector`. Are either empty?

Comment: Checked already. neither of them are empty.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the contents of `data_vector`? Also if you show the actual error backtrace that's often helpful.

Comment: (29, 7069) -  shape of data_vector
  (0, 4913) 0.00907251242871
  (0, 1663) 0.00484076475644
  (0, 5557) 0.00550325964944
  (0, 4979) 0.00447394143922
  (0, 2040) 0.00716837181356
  (0, 3065) 0.00828222266952
  (0, 1612) 0.00430739989088
  (0, 1576) 0.00716837181356
  (0, 3350) 0.0101863632847
  (0, 1229) 0.0101863632847
  (0, 4683) 0.00907251242871
  (0, 3646) 0.00576508569374
  (0, 1260) 0.0101863632847
  (0, 4939) 0.0101863632847
  (0, 3861) 0.00907251242871
  (0, 3024) 0.0101863632847
  (0, 542) 0.00828222266952